# Conv2DTranspose can't accept previous Conv2D output with message 'ValueError: Inputs should have rank 4.)

Tags: python, image, tensorflow, keras

When I ran the code below, I get the message 'ValueError: Inputs should have rank 4. Received input shape: (None, 169, 128, 16, 32)' where Conv2DTranspose command was executed and the result.

The result of 'model.summary()' indicate that output((None, 169, 128, 16, 32)) was generated by Conv2D before execution of Conv2DTranspose although Conv2DTranspose rejects the previous output saying that 'Inputs should have rank 4.'.

How can I fix this error?

```
############################ executed code #############################
num_hidden1 = 32
num_hidden2 = 64
num_hidden3 = 128
num_hidden4 = 64
num_hidden5 = 32
num_hidden6 = 32

######### start of network definition

  model= keras.Sequential()

#--- encode start

  model.add(Conv2D(num_hidden1,  kernel_size=(3,3), strides=(2,2), activation='relu', input_shape=x_train.shape, padding='same'))
  model.add(Conv2D(num_hidden1,  kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
  model.add(Conv2D(num_hidden1,  kernel_size=(3,3), strides=(2,2), activation='relu', padding='same'))

  model.add(Conv2D(num_hidden2, data_format='channels_first', kernel_size=(3,3), strides=(2,2), activation='relu', padding='same'))
  model.add(Conv2D(num_hidden2, data_format='channels_first', kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
  model.add(Conv2D(num_hidden2, data_format='channels_first', kernel_size=(3,3), strides=(2,2), activation='relu', padding='same'))

#--- encode out
  model.add(Conv2D(num_hidden3, data_format='channels_first', kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
  model.add(Conv2D(num_hidden3, data_format='channels_first', kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
  model.add(Conv2D(num_hidden3, data_format='channels_first', kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
  model.add(Conv2D(num_hidden3, data_format='channels_first', kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
  model.summary()

#--- decode start

  model.add(Conv2DTranspose(num_hidden4, data_format='channels_first', kernel_size=(3,3), strides=(2,2), activation='relu', padding='same'))
  model.add(Conv2DTranspose(num_hidden4, data_format='channels_first', kernel_size=(3,3), strides=(2,2), activation='relu', padding='same'))

  model.add(Conv2DTranspose(num_hidden5, data_format='channels_first', kernel_size=(3,3), strides=(2,2), activation='relu', padding='same'))
  model.add(Conv2DTranspose(num_hidden5, data_format='channels_first', kernel_size=(3,3), strides=(2,2), activation='relu', padding='same'))

  model.add(Conv2D(num_hidden5, data_format='channels_first', kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
  model.add(Conv2D(num_hidden6, data_format='channels_first', kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu', padding='same'))

#--- back to 3 channel

  model.add(Conv2D(3, data_format='channels_first', kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu', padding='same'))

####### end of network definition

# compile network
  model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error' , metrics=['accuracy'])


# do training
  num_itter=20

  model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=num_itter , batch_size=8 , validation_split=0.2 )

############################## result of execution ##################################
Model: "sequential_11"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_108 (Conv2D)          (None, 169, 128, 128, 32) 320       
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_109 (Conv2D)          (None, 169, 128, 128, 32) 9248      
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_110 (Conv2D)          (None, 169, 64, 64, 32)   9248      
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_111 (Conv2D)          (None, 169, 64, 32, 32)   36928     
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_112 (Conv2D)          (None, 169, 64, 32, 32)   36928     
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_113 (Conv2D)          (None, 169, 64, 16, 32)   36928     
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_114 (Conv2D)          (None, 169, 128, 16, 32)  73856     
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_115 (Conv2D)          (None, 169, 128, 16, 32)  147584    
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_116 (Conv2D)          (None, 169, 128, 16, 32)  147584    
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_117 (Conv2D)          (None, 169, 128, 16, 32)  147584    
=================================================================
Total params: 646,208
Trainable params: 646,208
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________

---------------------------------------------------------------------------

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-23-4694da30c921> in <module>()
     40 #--- decode start
     41 
---> 42 model.add(Conv2DTranspose(num_hidden4, data_format='channels_first', kernel_size=(3,3), strides=(2,2), activation='relu', padding='same'))
     43 model.add(Conv2DTranspose(num_hidden4, data_format='channels_first', kernel_size=(3,3), strides=(2,2), activation='relu', padding='same'))
     44 

7 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/convolutional.py in build(self, input_shape)
   1229     if len(input_shape) != 4:
   1230       raise ValueError('Inputs should have rank 4. Received input '
-> 1231                        'shape: ' + str(input_shape))
   1232     channel_axis = self._get_channel_axis()
   1233     if input_shape.dims[channel_axis].value is None:

ValueError: Inputs should have rank 4. Received input shape: (None, 169, 128, 16, 32)

################convolutional.py in build(self, input_shape)#################
  def build(self, input_shape):
    input_shape = tensor_shape.TensorShape(input_shape)
    if len(input_shape) != 4:
      raise ValueError('Inputs should have rank 4. Received input '
                       'shape: ' + str(input_shape))
    channel_axis = self._get_channel_axis()
    if input_shape.dims[channel_axis].value is None:
      raise ValueError('The channel dimension of the inputs '
                       'should be defined. Found `None`.')
    input_dim = int(input_shape[channel_axis])
    self.input_spec = InputSpec(ndim=4, axes={channel_axis: input_dim})
    kernel_shape = self.kernel_size + (self.filters, input_dim)
###########################################################################################
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is caused by passing the the x_train.shape into the first conv layer. You have to pass only the the real dimensions of the input data since the first argument is designated for number of samples. That way all the conv layers in your model will have a 4D input and not 5D input.

In other words, you are passing the the argument as if you had 4D data and keras adds another dimension for count of the samples.